# vba Excel data connection

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help. I have a workbook (A) and i want open another workbook (B) and run a macro that is inside B.
Workbook (B) have a macro that make a sql connection to another workbook (C) to extract data, when i run this macro in the workbook (B) work fine, but if i open the workbook (B) from workbook (A) and run the macro i get a message from Windows “The file is open” (WorkBooK (C)).
How can I skip this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPpmC.png)

I get the error when open the connection data.

The code to open the Workbook(B) is :

```
    Sub OpenWorkBookandRun()
    tarPath = "..............\"
    strfilename = "..........xlsm"

    Application.Workbooks.Open tarPath & strfilename
    'Run Macro
    Workbooks(strfilename).Activate
    Application.Run "'................'!Module1.Macro"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

And the code in the workbook (B) to open data origin is:

```
    ' Establezco los parametros de la conexion ADO, el RecordSet y la Cadena de conexion
Set oCONN = New ADODB.Connection
Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & OrigDatos & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
' Abro la conexion y ejecuto la sentencia SQL
If Not (oCONN Is Nothing) Then
  If (oCONN.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then oCONN.Close
End If
oCONN.Open strConn  <--- Line where i get the error
oRS.Open strSQL, oCONN, 1, 3
```

Note. Sometimes in the fisrt workbook I get the same messages, but only sometimes and I don’t know why because anybody has the origin of data open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the workbook (C) already open when you run the macro from Workbook (A)?
Other question is, do you need to write something in Workbook (C)? If you don't you can use a parameter in you connection string to connect with readonly, like this:

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Data Source=" & OrigDatos & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;""
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Worbook (C) is open ever, but i only need read a table with data. When i run workbook B and make the connection to C y dont receive the message or error, the connection open the workbook C in read mode. I will try the parameter of read only.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Notify = false.

```
Application.Workbooks.Open tarPath & strfilename, , , , , , , , , ,false
```

According to MSDN, the notify prompt has the following functionality,
"If the file cannot be opened in read/write mode, this argument is True to add the file to the file notification list. Microsoft Excel will open the file as read-only, poll the file notification list, and then notify the user when the file becomes available. If this argument is False or omitted, no notification is requested, and any attempts to open an unavailable file will fail."

Comment: thanks, i will try your solution and comment you if works fine.